# CodeIgniter pass different vars through template

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am new to CodeIgniter, and i'm having the following problem:

When i load the view from within the controller, i used the following code:

```
 $this->load->view('includes/header');
 $this->load->view('includes/main_menu');
 $this->load->view('show_users');
 $this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

Now i created a template that loads the header, menu, content and footer so i don't have to load all those views inside every controller. This all works fine, until i pass data through the template towards the view.

The situation is now like this:
controller - Template - view

Controller: (show_users.php)

```
$data['userdata'] = $this->users_model->get_all_users();
$data['page'] = 'show_users';

$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

Template: (template.php)

```
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view('includes/main_menu');
$this->load->view($page, $userdata);
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

View: (show_users.php)

```
<div id="users_table">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach($userdata as $r): ?>
            <tr><td><?php echo $r['id']; ?></td><td><?php echo $r['firstName']; ?></td><td><?php echo $r['lastName']; ?></td></tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

now i pass the 'userdata' variable towards the view by using

```
$this->load->view($page, $userdata);
```

and that works fine. But i want to use this template throughout the website, so the second parameter isnt always $userdata. (can be a random array, string etc with a different var name)

is there any way i can solve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work fine, assuming you use sensible naming:

```
 $data['userdata'] = $this->users_model->get_all_users();
 $data['page'] = 'show_users';
 $this->load->view('template', $data);

 $this->load->view($page, $userdata);
```

can also be:

```
 $data['view_data'] = $this->users_model->get_all_users();
 $this->load->view($page, $view_data);
```

By always using `$data['view_data']` in your controller, you can assign it any thing you want, as long as the index remains the same.

more examples:

```
 $data['view_data'] = some_other_method_thats_not_getting_users();
 $this->load->view($page, $view_data);
```

Comment: <code>$data['view_data']['view_data2'] = method();</code>  This is probably bad practice.